# Featuring tag <span> elements inside input line?

Tags: html, reactjs

In making this post, while selecting tags, once I've chosen a tag, the badge for the tag appears inline inside the input space I am writing inside of. I am trying to achieve some functionality which is quite similar, and I was wondering if anybody could give me a pointer on how one would achieve this type of functionality? That is, let's discuss the functionality here on StackOverflow rather than having me completely describe my personal situation, as I can adjust to my own needs.

I am attaching an image of what the "Tags" input box looks like once I've selected a tag for reference.

The only possible solution I had come up with on my own involved using dangerouslySetInnerHTML, which just sounds like something that ought to be avoided if possible judging by the name.

I am using React if that matters with regards to the answer.

[image]

Comment: Either press `F12` or right-click on that "input element" to open the dev console. Then you quickly realize, that SO is not using an input but a `div` with `content-editable="true"` to add tags. They don't use an `<input>` because it can't do that.

Answer (score -1):

dangerouslySetInnerHTML is React’s replacement for using innerHTML in the browser DOM. In general, setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack.

you can use `DOMPurify` to sanitize your HTML before inserting it in the DOM via dangerouslySetInnerHTML.

Comment: You completely miss the question. The question is not about what `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` or what it does. It's about how to input tags into an input element. An input element is a replaced element (empty) and as such has no `innerHTML`.

Comment: As it was assumed in the question from the name dangerouslySetInnerHTML , thats why i explained it.. and he said that , it was a possible solution but should be avoided as its dangerous .. i gave him a way to keep it safe. where i went wrong ? correct me if i am wrong @tacoshy

Comment: Like I said you missed the actual question. He tries to add tags in an input element such as the `jave` or the `css` tag here in SO. You completely ignored the question itself just saw one word and wrote an article about it that does not answer the question. You also completely ignore that your answer has no relevance as an input element can't be used here in the first place.